# Loss of data in inputStream while fetching data via Bluetooth HC-05 in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, hc-05

I'm unable to fetch all data from inputstream while connected via bluetooth hc-05 on my android app. Here is my code:

```
        val knownUUIDForDevice = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
        val remoteDevice: BluetoothDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddress)
        val btSocket: BluetoothSocket = remoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(knownUUIDForDevice)
        btSocket.connect()
        connectedThread = ConnectedThread(btSocket, rawDataMessageCallback)
        connectedThread.start()
```

My connectedThread code:

```
class ConnectedThread(private val btSocket: BluetoothSocket)
: Thread() {

private var inStream: InputStream? = null
internal var outStream: OutputStream? = null

init {
    inStream = btSocket.inputStream
    outStream = btSocket.outputStream
}

override fun run() {
    val buffer = ByteArray(512)
    inStream = btSocket.inputStream
    outStream = btSocket.outputStream
    while (true) {
        try {
            inStream!!.read(buffer)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println(e)
            break
        }

    }
}
```

}

When I tested connection between my device & realterm app, I was able to see all data. Application above is capable of receiving only about 80% of data. I'm sure it is not fault of device, because I'm able to see all data in realterm app.
What I've tried:

1) Add sleep before/after read method
2) wrap inputStream into buffered stream
3) used inStream!!.readBytes() instead of inStream!!.read(buffer) -> thread freezed up on this method (inside there was call to read method())
4) checking available data with available method(), but it gave me incorrect results - i.e. when stream was going to end, it shows 50 bytes were available, but actually I saw it was 200 bytes available in buffer... Anyway, according to documentation, I should never rely on this method.
5) Used IOUtils from apache commons & Bytestreams from guava -> result the same as in 3rd point, thread freeze
6) Changed size of buffer: tried 1, 10, 100, 256, 512, 1024, 10000  7

Question is: is it possible of loss of data in inputStream?

Comment: Which part was lost? first part or last part?

Comment: Last part, every time I do not receive about 20% last part of data.

Comment: Can you check buffer size of sender?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I think the problem is with the available method in the inpustream, because it returns incorrect value. When I'm reaching "end of my stream", last call to available returns less number of characters which can be read than in reality, i.e. it returns 100 characters, but read method fills buffer with 512 bytes of data. Then another call to read freezes thread, because it thinks stream is empty (now invocation of available returns 0).

Comment: I second Stanlkey, knowing what gets sends seems like critical for your issue.